# Ubuntu 18.04 Server Silently Becomes Unresponsive

Tags: 18.04, server, crash, headless

I have a small headless server, running Ubuntu 18.04. After some time (e.g. a day or two) the server becomes unresponsive; no SSH access, no ping response, no disk activity when the power button is pressed, it must be held to turn off the server.

When the server is running healthily and the power button is pressed, there is disk activity as it shuts down normally. So I think it is a pretty hard crash, not just e.g. the NIC becoming unresponsive.

My limited knowledge of system logs seems to show no errors at all. I have set up and verified that the kernel crash dump mechanism is working, but nothing is produced.

What should be my next steps in debugging this?

System specs in case it's relevant:

- AMD Ryzen 3 1200 (4 cores, 4 threads, 3.1GHz)
- Asrock AB350 Gaming-ITX/AC
- 1x 16GB DDR4-2666 CL19 **ECC** (verified running as ECC)
- Nvidia GeForce GT 710 (to make the system boot - CPU has no IG)
- 1x 250GB Crucial MX500 250GB 3D NAND M.2 Type 2280 Internal SSD (boot and system disk)
- 2x 4TB TOSHIBA HDWQ140, software RAID 1 (mirrored, spun down for power saving after 30min)

Many thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: If there are no errors in the logs at all, and no .crash files, then start looking at common hardware faults for your model.

Comment: Look at the last logs before reboot with `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e`

Comment: Same thing on same Ryzen 3 1200 and Ubuntu 18.04,
At the same time I have exactly the same components but CPU is AMD A8 9600 and the uptime is already 28 days. However the Ryzen system stops responding usually in less than a day. No solution just yet for me.

Comment: @waltinator That's something I had stumbled across myself; the last output is from the successful boot, nothing afterwards.

Comment: @pavko_a Interesting. I was considering upgrading the CPU, which might get me away from the problem. I also haven't checked if there is a newer BIOS version, do you know if you are on the latest?

Comment: @EthanFowler we've got a couple bios options disabled (cool'n'quiet, c6-state and some power saving options, cannot recall which ones) and now it's working for past 48 hours without any problems. I have googled and this looks to be a common issue with ryzen and linux